# Unable to edit input (material-ui & react-draggable)

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, dom-events, event-listener

I am unable enter input inside TextField that is looped over an array present in the react state.

Please follow the codesandbox url to see the code. **You can proceed the first page without entering any input** as I have handled that at the code level for convenience.

[Code Sandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-shape-woz2p)

Comment: In Creator.js, You are missing `value` prop in your TextField.

Comment: @Abhishekchandel the issue is on SplitView.js sorry I didn't mentioned that.
Creator.js is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `react-draggable` causing it.

I've noticed it when I tried focusing on your input, and a class of `react-draggable` was added on the body.

Try adding `enableUserSelectHack` prop on `Draggable` component and set it to **false**, to see if this fixes your problem. Seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/issues/410).

```
<Draggable enableUserSelectHack={false} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's enough just to set the property `cancel` with the input class this way:

```
<Draggable cancel=".class-of-input">
```

If it's purposed several element click or focus interactions, then:

```
<Draggable cancel=".class-first, .class-second, ...">
```